# Error in opencv - python3 (detectMultiScale) Face recognition

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to create a face detection program. When I execute the below code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('../../Practica - Proyectos/Practica - 
OpenCV/cascades/data/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml')

captura = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


while(True):
    ret, frame = captura.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.5, minNeighbors=5)
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        print(x,y,w,h)


cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break


captura.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The following error occurs:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\xampp\htdocs\Practica - Proyectos\Practica - OpenCV\facialRec.py", line 20, in faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.5, minNeighbors=5) cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.1) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp:1698: error: (-215) !empty() in function cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale

I understand that there is a problem with the route but I can not guess why it does not execute. The code is supposed to execute and read the different points on my face.

Thank you very much for your time in advance.

Comment: print `face_cascade` in the terminal and see what it prints. Ensure the path points to the `xml` file.

Comment: Thanks, but I can not find the error.

Comment: Where is your file `haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml` located? That path must be placed in `cv2.CascadeClassifier('place it here')` Eg. for me it would be `face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:/Users/Jackson/Desktop/Stack/face_detection/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml')`

Comment: when you print `face_cascade` in the console, it  should return something like: `<CascadeClassifier 00000000163C00D0>`. This means that the cascade classifier has been instantiated.